# label override in uicollectionview in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

Please help ...
this code is over ride the label ....

cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
 static NSString *identifier = @"cellIdentifier";

[self.mycollectionViewOutlet registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

 UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

 cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];

 self.mycollectionViewOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

 objects_products * ob = [self.recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 UILabel *recipelableView = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];

 if (!recipelableView)  

      recipelableView=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,115,100,50)];

      [recipelableView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12]];

      recipelableView.textColor=[UIColor redColor];

      [recipelableView setText:ob.price];

      recipelableView.tag = LABEL_TAG;

      [cell addSubview:recipelableView];

  return cell;
```

Comment: R U using coustom cell?

Comment: What is your problem? also is the code you pasted inside cellForItemAt... ?

Answer (score 0):

may be it will help for you, you added multi times Label to cell. please add label to cell in condition (it added only one time) as follows.

```
static NSString *identifier = @"cellIdentifier";

[self.mycollectionViewOutlet registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]     forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

 UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

 cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];

 self.mycollectionViewOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

 objects_products * ob = [self.recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 UILabel *recipelableView = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];

if (!recipelableView)   {
    recipelableView=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,115,100,50)]; 
   [recipelableView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12]];

  recipelableView.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
  recipelableView.tag = LABEL_TAG;
  [cell addSubview:recipelableView];
}


  [recipelableView setText:ob.price];

  return cell;
```